# Would an illegitimate child of a monarch have been recognized at the Russian court?

Tags: 19th-century, russia, monarchy

For purposes of a novel I am writing I would like to know if an illegitimate son or daughter of a 19th century Russian tsar would have been recognized by the court. Would it matter if the birth was before or after the tsar's coronation?

Comment: What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. Can you explain why any relevant Wikipedia pages and/or google searches didn't answer the question?  [SE sites work best if the questions are supported by preliminary research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/2085030)

Comment: Yes, I've done some searching of various sites without finding a definitive answer. It may be that there is no single answer: how such children were treated, whether they were recognized, or whether they could inherit apparently varied.

Comment: It really helps if you document your prior research in your questions. That way, people don't duplicate your research, or simply tell you what you already know.  You might find it helpful to review the [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: I guess [Tsar Paul I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_I_of_Russia) doesn't count.

Comment: It would be [the Emperor's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_of_All_Russia) coronation.

Answer (score 7):

The term they used was "**[Royal Bastard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_bastard)**"  referring to an illegitimate child of a reigning monarch.  How they were treated, "recognized by court", was entirely up to the ruling monarch.

Royal Bastards of Russian Monarchs include:

- Count **[Alexei Grigorievich Bobrinsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobrinsky)**,  of Catherine the Great
- **[Joséphine Koberwein](https://www.costumecocktail.com/2017/03/06/josephine-koberwein-ca-1840s/)** of tzar Nicholas II of Russia
- **[Nikolai Lukash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikolai_Lukash)** tsar Alexander I of Russia
- **[Sofia Sergeyevna Trubetskaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sofia_Sergeyevna_Trubetskaya)** either Prince Trubetskoy, or tsar Nicholas I of Russia.

Other Notable royal bastards in history but not from Russia include:

- **[Henry FitzRoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_FitzRoy,_Duke_of_Richmond_and_Somerset)**, Duke of Richmond, son of King Henry VIII of England,
- **[James Scott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Scott,_1st_Duke_of_Monmouth)**, Duke of Monmouth, son of Charles II.

I Also found this link listing general **[illegitimate children of monarchs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Illegitimate_children_of_monarchs)**.

Comment: [Fitzroy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitzroy) is actually a common last name for that kind of child (the word is Anglo-Norman for "Son of the King")

Comment: another notable bastard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_the_Conqueror

Comment: @jk  Yeah that's an important one.